# Reason for VM Pin in S-882Z Series Charge Pump?

Tags: components, datasheet, charge-pump

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has any idea why this S-882Z Series charge pump uses a VM (voltage monitor) pin instead of the Vout pin that most charge pumps use? And in general, why is the pinout so unique? This pump notably has a small input voltage, so I am wondering if that has something to do with it. I've been trying to find this information on my own, but since no other charge pumps I've seen have a similar pin/pinout I've had a hard time finding more details.

Here is the data sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10LGZZtUPSExxCMJCII5GGYEg9W6X9IpH/view

Answer (score 1):

This device is not intended for use as a step-up converter. It is intended to be used to guarantee start-up of a second converter. Read the rest of the datasheet.

VM is used not as an output, but to monitors the output of the second converter, as shown in the example below. There are several diagrams to assist with the use of this device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That circuit is designed to power intermittent or very light loads from low voltage/low power sources so it is designed with efficiency in mind.  The Vm pin puts the circuit into a low power (0.5 μA vs 0.5mA) shutdown state when the desired output voltage is reached.  This voltage is set with a resistor divider as shown on page 9 of [the datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/360/S882Z_E-20950.pdf) (don't make people click random google drive files).